# NHibernate QueryOver subquery with concat and max

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm new with NHibernate 3 and QueryOver and I'm trying to translate this Oracle SQL to a NHibernate QueryOver expression:

```
  SELECT *  
  FROM MYTABLE T1  
  WHERE T1.ID= 'ID'  
  AND T1.TYPE= 'TYPE'  
  AND T1.DATADATE= '20130101'  
  AND (T1.GENERATIONDATE || T1.GENERATIONHOUR) =  
    (SELECT MAX (T2.GENERATIONDATE || T2.GENERATIONHOUR) 
    FROM MYTABLE T2  
    WHERE T1.ID= T2.ID
    AND T1.TYPE= T2.TYPE
    AND T1.DATADATE= T2.DATADATE)
```

All five columns are part of the table primary key, and all I want is to filter selecting the newest rows concatenating the GENERATIONDATE (NVARCHAR2(8) date in 'yyyyMMdd' format) and GENERATIONHOUR (NVARCHAR2(2) hour in 'HH' format) fields.

I have a static class as QueryOver provider for my class, so for one simple Query i'm doing:

```
class MyTableQueryOver
{
    static QueryOver<MyTable, MyTable> ByIDAndTypeAndDate(string id, string type, string date)
    {
         return QueryOver.Of<MyTable>()
             .Where(x => x.Id == id 
                 && x.Type == type 
                 && x.Date == date);
    }
}
```

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance.